# IE 11 doesn't process font declaration correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-11, google-font-api

The following font declaration is not working in [Internet Explorer 11](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie).

```
font:300 28px/1.1em 'Lora', arial, sans-serif;
```

The text is displayed in `arial` instead of `Lora`. `Lora` is a [Google Font](https://www.google.com/fonts).

It's working however in [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox), [QupZilla](http://www.qupzilla.com/) and [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/).

But when I change the declaration to

```
font:300 28px/1.1em 'Lora';
```

it's working in IE 11.

What could be the problem?

---

**It gets even stranger**: When I save the website as an `*.html` file to my local disc, the font is displayed correctly. :-(

Comment: Does the problem persist after clearing your cache? If so, could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: So when does the page *not* work? As uploaded to a server? Where? And how are you using the font, as hosted by Google or otherwise?

Comment: @MrLister Clearing the cache doesn't help.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It does **not** work on the server. The font is hosted by Google. And when I switch to – let's say – _Open Sans_, everything is working fine.

Comment: Not reproducible, tested with http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/lorafont.html

Comment: Using the font weight 300 is illogical, since Lora does not have that weight; this should have no effect, though: the normal (400) weight will be used instead.

Comment: Hit F12. Look for messages on the CONSOLE tab as the page loads.

Comment: Fortunately we switched font so I don't have to bother with this problem any longer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Embed Google font on `<head>`.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and then try below css

```
.class{
      font-family: 'Lora', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight:400;
      font-size:28px/1.1em;
    }
```