# I Cant get @font face to work for internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

I have been trying to use a custom font it seems to work on everything but not internet explorer 11. Am I missing something really easy here to make this work?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'comfortaa';
src: url('Comfortaa.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('Comfortaa.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('../fonts/Comfortaa_Regular.ttf.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('../fonts/Comfortaa_Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, 
   iOS    */
     url('../fonts/Comfortaa_Regular.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */


}

@font-face {
font-family: 'comfortaabold';
src: url('Comfortaa-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('Comfortaa-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('../fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('../fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('../fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */


}
```

Comment: I have read somewhere I might need to move the font to somewhere else maybe top level of the site?

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to coding, maybe the easiest solution is to embed the font by putting it in the beginning of your `<head>` tag like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

There are several similar questions asked and answered that can help you troubleshoot:

- [How to make Google Fonts work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694060/)
- [IE 11 “bulletproof” font-face and fall back fonts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054158/)
- [Google Fonts not working in Internet Explorer (IE) 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561414/)
- [IE 11 doesn't process font declaration correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657744/)
- [IE Intranet Compatibility View not including certain font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901017/)
- and more...

It is wise to do a search before you post a question.

If you'd like to test your site in Explorer on a Mac, there is even questions and answers for that. [This one should work well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103564) if you have several GBs to spare. If not you can look into the new Azure RemoteApp for Windows, Mac OSX, iOS or Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for IE 11

```
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: "MyFont_Lite";
        src: url("../Fonts/myfont.ttf") format("truetype");
        src: url("../Fonts/myfont.woff") format("woff");
    }
```